# How to get a JButton on top of an image (background)?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am using an image as a background and then I have another image as a JButton. The Background image currently overlaps the button, so you can't see it. When I comment repaint() out, then the button is in front, however because I re-located the button, that space is faded out of the background image. So basically, what must I do with my code to put the button in front of the background image( with the background image still intact)?

```
public class Start extends JFrame {

JPanel jp = new JPanel();
JButton startButton = new JButton();
private Image dbImage;
private Graphics dbg;
Image backgroundFirst;
int backx;
int backy;

public Start() {
    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(
            "C:/Users/Mel/workspace/camptycoon/javagame/src/javagame/background1.png");
    backgroundFirst = i.getImage();

    startButton
            .setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    "C:/Users/Mel/workspace/camptycoon/javagame/src/javagame/start.png"));
    jp.add(startButton);
    startButton.setLayout(getLayout());
    add(jp);
    validate();

    // Frame Properties
    setTitle("Counselor Training");
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(755, 600);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}

public LayoutManager getLayout() {
    int x = 540;
    int y = 475;
    startButton.setLocation(x, y);
    startButton.setBorder(null);

    return null;

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    dbImage = createImage(getWidth(), getHeight());
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    backx = 10;
    backy = 30;

    g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    g.drawImage(backgroundFirst, backx, backy, this);
    //repaint();
}

}
```

Comment: That's a fair whack of code. Are you sure you can't trim it down to the bare essentials?

Answer (score 3):

I know of a few commonly used solutions:

- Use a JLabel that holds the image in its ImageIcon as your contentPane making sure to give it a decent layout manager, or
- Using a JPanel as the contentPane and drawing the image in its `paintComponent(...)` method.
- Use of a JLayeredPane with the image held by a component (JLabel perhaps) on the bottom-most layer. I've used this mainly for animation work where I wanted to lift components/sprites from one layer to another.

---

Additional notes:

- Don't forget to use `@Override` annotations for all methods that you think are overrides, because you may be surprised to find out that one in fact isn't (i.e., your `paintComponent(...) method above).
- You almost never override a JFrame's `paint(...)` method as it's likely not doing what you think it's doing and you're in danger of unwanted side effects.
- In fact it's a good idea to avoid overriding the `paint(...)` method of *any* component.
- You should strive to avoid using a null layout.
- Your `getLayout()` method override looks skanky to me. Don't do this.
- If you want to nest JPanels on top of an image displaying component, be sure to set the overlying JPanels (or other components) as being non-opaque by calling `setOpaque(false)` on them.

Comment: +1, ditto for all the suggestions. In addition I would suggest don't use the setSize() method. If you use the first suggestion then the preferred size of the label will be the size of the image. If you do custom painting on the panel then you will be responsible for setting the preferred size of the panel. In both cases you would then invoke pack() on the frame to let the frame determine the appropriate size taking into account borders and title bar. Then invoke setVisible(). The validate() method is unnecessary